# How to get multiple key value pairs from list of JSON dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file called "hostnames" formatted like below

```
{
    'propertyName': 'www.property1.com',
    'propertyVersion': 1,
    'etag': 'jbcas6764023nklf78354',
    'rules': {
        'name': 'default',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Route',
            'children': [],
            'behaviors': [{
                'name': 'origin',
                'options': {
                    'originType': 'CUSTOMER',
                    'hostname': 'www.origin1.com',
```

and I wanted to get the values of keys "propertyName" and "hostname" and have a new JSON file like below

```
'properties': [{
    'propertyName': 'www.property1.com',
    'hostnames': ['www.origin1.com', 'www.origin2.com']
}, {
    'propertyName': 'www.property1.com',
    'hostnames': ['www.origin1.com', 'www.origin2.com']
}]
```

my code looks like this

```
hostnames = result.json()
hostnameslist = [host['hostname'] for host in hostnames['rules']['children']['behaviors']['options']]
print(hostnameslist)
```

but I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: The data you show does not represent valid JSON. It appears to be part of a Python dictionary. It does not contain 'www.origin2.com'

Comment: hint: you're trying to slice the `children` list using a string instead of a number. possibly you want to iterate over the items in `children`? It'd help if you gave a full JSON entry, not the truncated one you have here, if you want help with a full solution.

Comment: Oops sorry but yeah wanted to have a json file containing the propertynames and its corresponding hostnames. www.origin2.com is not there, just wanted to demonstrate that there could be multiple hostnames per propertyname.

Comment: @francorocks check the answer I just typed! Might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an assumption about how the OP's data might be structured.

Recursive navigation of the dictionary to find all/any values associated with a dictionary key of 'hostname' appears to be well-suited here.

Doing it this way obviates the need for knowledge about the depth of the dictionary or indeed any of the dictionary key names except (obviously) 'hostname'.

Of course, there may be other dictionaries within the "master" dictionary that contain a 'hostname' key. If that's the case then this function may return values that are not needed/wanted.

```
data = {
    'propertyName': 'www.property1.com',
    'propertyVersion': 1,
    'etag': 'jbcas6764023nklf78354',
    'rules': {
        'name': 'default',
        'children': [{
            'name': 'Route',
            'children': [],
            'behaviors': [{
                'name': 'origin',
                'options': {
                    'originType': 'CUSTOMER',
                    'hostname': 'www.origin1.com'
                }
            },
            {
                'name': 'origin',
                'options': {
                    'originType': 'CUSTOMER',
                    'hostname': 'www.origin2.com'
                }
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
}

def get_hostnames(d):
    def _get_hostnames(_d, _l):
        if isinstance(_d, dict):
            if 'hostname' in _d:
                _l.append(_d['hostname'])
            else:
                for _v in _d.values():
                    _get_hostnames(_v, _l)
        else:
            if isinstance(_d, list):
                for _v in _d:
                    _get_hostnames(_v, _l)
        return _l
    return _get_hostnames(d, [])


result = {'properties': [{'propertyName': data.get('propertyName'), 'hostnames': get_hostnames(data)}]}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'properties': [{'propertyName': 'www.property1.com', 'hostnames': ['www.origin1.com', 'www.origin2.com']}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your expertise. I am getting my desired result now although ultimately I wanted to have a single json result like above (updated my desired output). Also, hope it's not too much, could you kindly explain briefly how your code works. I am a beginner in Python or coding in general.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a list elements with a string index ('behaviors').
Try:

```
hostnames = result.json()
hostnameslist = []
for child in hostnames['rules']['children']:
    for behavior in child['behaviors']:
        if behavior['name'] == 'origin':
            hostnameslist.append(behavior['options']['hostname'])

properties = [{
    'propertyName': hostnames['propertyName'],
    'hostnames': hostnameslist
}]
```

Comment: Hi Nova thanks for your time. For some reason, I'm not getting the value for hostname key. Tried to print "properties" and here [{'propertyName': 'personal.macquarie.com.au', 'hostnames': []}]

Comment: Then seems that hostnameslist is empty! If you still didn't solve that yet, and you're sure that it's not empty, please write a reply, I'll update the code so it will give you an insight if it is empty or not

Comment: Hi Nova thanks a lot, another answer below works for me.